# Vim: print lines from hidden buffers

Tags: vim, vimscript

I'd like echo line from a hidden buffer without moving my cursor. Something like this:

```
:redir! > /tmp/myfile
:1,$print 3
:redir end
```

(I want to inspect hidden buffers without changing the window layout or the cursor position.)

The above works great for the current buffer, but `:print` doesn't take a buffer as an argument.

Is there some vim command that prints the lines in a buffer?

(And FWIW, I can't use `:w` because that also changes the names and numbers of the open buffers.)

Comment: No. Buffer numbers *never* change. Why don't you simply `:b` to that hidden buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access lines from any buffer via the `getbufline()` function. Example:

```
for line in getbufline(3, 1, '$')
    echo line
endfor
```